# Making an image or background image fade away on div spin?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to create spinning divs that show an image when not being hovered and then when hovered they spin and show text and a background color. I have the spin action working and the background color changing and the text appearing when the div spins. However I can not find a way to insert an image into the div and have this image fade away on hover, when the spin occurs.

My code is below can somebody please tell me where I have gone wrong?

[I have also included a livelink](http://www.cambridgedesigncompany.com/newpage.html) to help you answer the question however this will be removed when the question has been answered for future posterity of the post.

***HTML***

```css
  .trigger {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  .trigger.large {
    width: 400px;
  }
  .trigger.vertical {
    height: 400px;
  }
  .trigger.vertical * {
    height: 400px;
  }
  .hover-img,
  .hover-img.hover_effect {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #CCCCB2;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .trigger.large .hover-img,
  .trigger.large .hover-img.hover_effect {
    width: 400px;
  }
  .trigger:hover > .hover-img {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #999;
  }
  #container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .row {
    display: flex;
  }
  .col {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .trigger.large .hover-img,
  .trigger.large .hover-img.hover_effect {
    width: 400px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="trigger vertical">
        <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img">Text Here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="trigger">
        <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img">Text Here
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="trigger">
        <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img">Text Here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- </div>
     <div  class="row">-->
    <div class="col">
      <div class="trigger">
        <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img">Text Here</div>
      </div>
      <div class="trigger">
        <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img">Text Here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="trigger">
        <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img">Text Here</div>
      </div>
      <div class="trigger">
        <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img">Text Here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="trigger">
      <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img">Text Here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger">
      <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img">Text Here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger large">
      <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img">Text Here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="trigger">
      <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img">Text Here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger">
      <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img">Text Here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger">
      <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img">Text Here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger">
      <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img">Text Here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You cannot "fade" a background image..only actual images..and there don't seem to be any in your HTML

Comment: @Paulie_D sorry, fade an image in the body of the div. There is none in there as when I put them in nothing was showing anyway... I really have no idea how to take this forward so if you have any alternative suggestions on how to get the same result I would be very grateful.

Comment: no just an honest mistake from a person that has a stinking cold and would rather be at home in bed than in the office :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add select the image to `display:none`hover when the parent is hovered.

```css
.trigger {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.trigger.large {
  width: 400px;
}
.trigger.vertical {
  height: 400px;
}
.trigger.vertical * {
  height: 400px;
}
.hover-img,
.hover-img.hover_effect {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #CCCCB2;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.trigger.large .hover-img,
.trigger.large .hover-img.hover_effect {
  width: 400px;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #999;
}
#container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.col {
  display: inline-block;
}
.trigger.large .hover-img,
.trigger.large .hover-img.hover_effect {
  width: 400px;
}
.hover-img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.trigger:hover .hover-img img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="trigger vertical">
        <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-100-100-2.jpg" alt="" />Text Here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="trigger vertical">
        <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-100-100-3.jpg" alt="" />Text Here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### With this one you can have a different image for each div

How about...
(**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joe_young/snuhapqk/)**)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".trigger").hover(function() {          /*On hover of one of the divs*/
            $(this).find( 'img' ).fadeOut();  /*Fade out the img inside it
            $(this).find( 'p' ).fadeIn();     /*And fade in the 'p'*/

    });
        $(".trigger").mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).find( 'img' ).fadeIn();
             //$(this).text("");

    });
});
```

And they you'd add the `img` and `p` to the `.trigger` div

e.g.

```
<div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img">
<img src="http://exmoorpet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cat.png" width="130px">
<p>Text here</p>
```

Comment: the thing is the squares will not have the same image, they will have different images :) I did think of this way but this would only work if all the divs had the same image

Comment: Ah oh sorry, I've done one with jQuery now, oh well. And with this one, each sqare can have a different image.

Comment: This any better? @steviepeters

Comment: thanks that looks and feels so much better than my CSS way, I think I'll use your way, however my only issue is that in the divs where you have the images the text on the reverse side disappears.

Comment: Ah I will have a look at that. Bear with. @steviepeters

Comment: your soooo awesome... This is why I have had so much trouble with it... maybe i should start using front page and make a single page site lol

Comment: Nooo stick to coding ;) @steviepeters. I've got something just about to update my JSFiddle

Comment: @Jofish: Jquery really wouldn't be the most appropriate for styling elements.

Comment: It was just the easiest way but oh well @jbutler483

Comment: @Jofish: *Really* not the easiest way. In fact, resorting to Jquery fro this would've been one seriously inefficient way when css (cascading ***styling*** sheet) is ***designed for this***.

Comment: Ok fair enough, but I couldn't work out a way by CSS, and had a jQuery way that *worked,* so might as well post it if it could help him in the slightest.

Comment: And also, as opposed to the accepted answer, the images in mine **fade** out and in as requested. And also with yours the divs don't rotate, simply fade. (I'm not trying to be picky). But anyway it doesn't matter now, there is more than one way to solve the problem. @jbutler483

Answer (score 1):

you can use a pseudo element for this, which will reduce your markup a lot:

```css
.hovereffect{
  height:200px;
  width:300px;
  background:lightgray;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  }
.hovereffect:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transition:all 0.8s;
  opacity:1;
  }

.hovereffect:hover:before{
  opacity:0;
  }

#thisone:before{
    background:url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/200);
  }
#thistwo:before{
    background:url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300);
  }
```

```html
<div class="hovereffect" id="thisone">I'm a load of text you wanted to see</div>
<div class="hovereffect" id="thistwo">I'm also a load of text you see?</div>
```

**Note**

By using a class in this way, you can quite quickly include functionality for *different images* if you so desire. I have given your different elements an ID, and so you can alter the div's `:before` elements' background accordingly.

Comment: thank you for your help man, its just I need a different image for each div.

Comment: @steviepeters: see edited snippet. As I said, could be altered for this.